# How to to bury 40 foot flag pole?

Tags: concrete, support, pole

I got a 40ft flag pole that is schedule 40 pipe welded together every 10ft with couplers.

My questions are:

- How deep I should put it?
- What diameter base?
- Can I use a Sonotube?

The area I live in gets quite a bit of rain and some pretty heavy wind. I can get gusts up to 100mph.

Comment: I don't expect sched40 PVC to be able to withstand the forces a flagpole will endure

Comment: How large diameter of pipe? Is it stepped to smaller pipe as you go up? 
It may take a combination of depth and width with that kind of wind forces. You are talking about schedule 40 metal pipe I hope.

Comment: Lacking adequate details, **drill a 25 foot hole and drop it in.** Practically speaking, it's normal to make flagpoles able to be lowered for maintenance, since otherwise you need to rent a lift every time the pulley jams or it needs a coat of paint. But the 25 foot hole will allow you to use a stepladder, as well as holding the pole in the wind until it bends or breaks.

Comment: it's impossible to know how much to dig without knowing how strong  your ground is.  I suspect the answer will involve large augers and/or pile drivers.

Comment: What's the pipe diameter? Are you using a ground sleeve? What size is that?

Comment: Why would one weld couplings ? Welding introduces possible problems with cracks .

Comment: As far as I know, there is no rule of thumb here. This question needs to be put to a structural engineer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is dependent on site related conditions (soil, wind exposure, etc) and needs to be put to a local structural engineer to get a proper (safe) answer

Comment: @ratchetfreak Sched 40 also exists in steel pipe.  "welded, with couplers" raises some questions, though; with steel you generally do one or the other.

Comment: Better yet, an 81 foot hole and a 40 foot hydraulic cylinder. When the wind gets bad or the pulley jams or it needs painting, just retract it into the hole in the ground. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Place it in a trench 40 feet long with 18" of cover. In the future you can pull wires through it. (It' been a long week).

Comment: Nailed this answer!

Comment: I'm glad you said it so I didn't have to.